# binding an event of a Jquery third party plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, event-handling, event-binding

i've found a nice popup modal ([animatedmodal](https://github.com/joaopereirawd/animatedModal.js/blob/master/demo/demos.html)) with some cool options but, it seems like it lacks of some functionality it has very nice stetics by the way but i think a web designer made it but the forgort what i need haha.Now i'm trying to hack this but i have short knowledge on javascript may be later on i can contribute to this project and make it better.

so the idea behind is getting know who fired the custom event its named animatedModal(); i manage to do know this by binding a click event and wrapping the caller and then passing it to a new function but the first click event never fires up after that you press again and everything goes ok!

please help me =)

this is the plugin demo and examples.

```
  <!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>DEMOS</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">
        <style>
            #btn-close-modal {
                width:100%;
                text-align: center;
                cursor:pointer;
                color:#fff;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!--Call your modal-->
        <ul>
            <li><a id="demo01" href="#animatedModal">DEMO01</a></li>
            <li><a id="demo02" href="#modal-02">DEMO02</a></li>
        </ul>


        <!--DEMO01-->
        <div id="animatedModal">
            <!--THIS IS IMPORTANT! to close the modal, the class name has to match the name given on the ID -->
            <div  id="btn-close-modal" class="close-animatedModal"> 
                CLOSE MODAL
            </div>

            <div class="modal-content">
                <!--Your modal content goes here-->
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--DEMO02-->
        <div id="modal-02">
            <!--"THIS IS IMPORTANT! to close the modal, the class name has to match the name given on the ID-->
            <div  id="btn-close-modal" class="close-modal-02"> 
                CLOSE MODAL
            </div>

            <div class="modal-content">
                <!--Your modal content goes here-->
            </div>
        </div>


        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/animatedModal.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            //demo 01
            $("#demo01").animatedModal();
            //demo 02
      //i need something like this


            $("#demo02").animatedModal({
                modalTarget:'modal-02',
                animatedIn:'lightSpeedIn',
                animatedOut:'bounceOutDown',
                color:'#3498db',
                // Callbacks
                beforeOpen: function() {
                    console.log("The animation was called");
                },           
                afterOpen: function() {
                    console.log("The animation is completed");
                }, 
                beforeClose: function() {
                    console.log("The animation was called");
                }, 
                afterClose: function() {
                    console.log("The animation is completed");
                }
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

i need something like this.

```
$(".deletePieza").animatedModal({
                    modalTarget: 'deletePiezad',
                    animatedIn: 'bounceInUp',
                    animatedOut: 'bounceOut',
                    color: '#d5d117',
                    afterClose: Hellow($(this))
                });
```

i've tried with this

```
function Hellow(me) {
                console.log($(this));
                console.log(this);
                alert("sayonara");
                //$("a.deletePieza").parentsUntil("div.panelPiezas").css("background", "white");
                $(me).parentsUntil("div.panelPiezas").css("background", "white");
            };

                $(".deletePieza").animatedModal({
                    modalTarget: 'deletePiezad',
                    animatedIn: 'bounceInUp',
                    animatedOut: 'bounceOut',
                    color: '#d5d117',
                    afterClose: $.proxy(Hellow,$(this))
                });
```

or

i've tried somethin with $.proxy() and triggering manually the click event but it does not fires up

```
function goal(winner) {
                $(winner).parentsUntil("div.panelPiezas").css("background", "white");
            }

            function Paint(me) {
                var againme = me;
                $("#deletePiezad").css("visibility", "visible");
                //$("a.deletePieza").parentsUntil("div.panelPiezas").css("background", "white");
                $(".deletePieza").animatedModal({
                            modalTarget: 'deletePiezad',
                            animatedIn: 'bounceInUp',
                            animatedOut: 'bounceOut',
                            color: '#d5d117',
                            afterClose: goal(againme)
                 });

            };

            $(".deletePieza").animatedModal($.proxy(Paint,$(this)));
```

another try! and still uneffective,after debugin with firebug this shows up
[image]

```
function paintme(elementtopaint) {
                $(elementtopaint).css("font-size", "40px");
            }
            //demo 02
            $("#demo02").animatedModal({
                modalTarget: 'modal-02',
                animatedIn: 'lightSpeedIn',
                animatedOut: 'bounceOutDown',
                color: '#3498db',
                // Callbacks
                beforeOpen: function () {
                    console.log("The animation was called");
                },
                afterOpen: function () {
                    console.log("The animation is completed");
                },
                beforeClose: function () {
                    console.log("The animation was called");
                },
                afterClose: jQuery.proxy(function (event) {
                    console.log("hey");
                    //paintme(event.target);
                    var cons = event.target;
                    console.log(this);
                    //$("#demo02").css("font-size", "40px");
                }, this)
            });
```

achieved but its bugged!

```
//in the css .container{visibility:hidden} //other wise the plugin dosen't hide the containers block and  works unproperly
 $(".deletePieza").animatedModal();

            function Hellow(me) {
                $(me).parentsUntil("div.panelPiezas").css("background", "white");
                //$("a.deletePieza").parentsUntil("div.panelPiezas").css("background", "white");

            };
            $("a.deletePieza").on("click", function () {
                var caller= $(this);
                $("#deletePiezad").css("visibility", "visible");
                //$(this).parentsUntil("div.panelPiezas").css("background", "white");
                $(".deletePieza").animatedModal({
                    modalTarget: 'deletePiezad',
                    animatedIn: 'bounceInUp',
                    animatedOut: 'bounceOut',
                    color: '#d5d117',
                    afterClose: Hellow(caller)
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You may call the modal with this line:

```
$('#demo01').click();
```

Comment: Kindly give a better description to your answer so that its useful.